# Can I append apex elements to html with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apex

In a visualforce page, if I have a DOM completely created dynamically with jQuery, could I append the following code dynamically too?

```
        <div id="file">
            <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file" title="Upload Attachment" styleclass="fileType"/> 
        </div><br />
```

Can I append apex elements to html with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.append()`:

```
 $('#file').append('<apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file" title="Upload Attachment" styleclass="fileType"/>');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LKUbr/2/)**

Comment: I'm pretty sure this approach won't work. Maybe with regular html elements, but not with apex elements.

Comment: Sorry, I did, it doesnt work. I was really hoping it would but no joy.